# Can i define generic size that fits to any device? bootstrap

Tags: css

I started to work with bottstrap. And the amazing thing about that thing - its giving the ability to control the width of blocks on the screen - to fit to any size of device as comfortable as can. 
The code that alowed to help me with the width is:

```
class = 'col-md-2'
```

My question is -
There is any way to do that exactly thing just with height of blocks? because when i make a site - the widht is suitable in any device (again,, because col-md...)
but the height is different. and i dont want that.

Comment: There is no such functionality in native Bootstrap's styles. However you can custom style it with `vh` styling unit like `height: 100vh` will set the height of blocks equal to 100% viewport height.

Comment: ill check for it! thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `row-eq-height` and you can check the documentation here http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: its better then use 'height: 100vh' as the guy above said?

Comment: whatever, the important thing is to achieve the result desired... if both do the same thing you just need to use the bootstrap to follow the same  pattern